# Remove a value without removing the entire row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, outliers

I have a dataframe in R where I have a few outliers. I want to remove these outliers, but don't want to remove the entire row as the outlier is just in one of the columns; the rest of the data is fine.

For a reproducible example, how would I remove the highest value in the Age column of the titanic_train dataframe (which is ~80), but leave the rest of the data for that passenger (in this case the highest value belongs to PassengerID # 631).

I started by pulling in the data and making a boxplot and labeling the Passenger IDs so I can see which ID has the highest age.

```
library(titanic)
library(ggrepel)
library(tidyverse)
```

```
titanic_train %>% ggplot(aes(x = Sex, y = Age)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.7, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.15, height = 0.15, alpha = 0.4)+ 
  geom_text(aes(label = PassengerId))
```

This told me that the greatest age is ~80, so I tried to only select the Age < 79 -- in this case I know that the Passenger ID is 631

```
no.631.age <- titanic_train %>%
  filter(Age < 79)
```

This removes the highest age value, but doesn't do what I want because when I look at the data, it removed the entire row for Passenger ID 631 -- not just the age value.

```
titanic_train$PassengerId
no.631.age$PassengerId
```

Can anyone tell me how to just remove the Age, and not the entire row?

Comment: Remove a value without removing the entire row? Do you mean to replace that value with `NA`? Try `titanic_train %>% mutate(Age = replace(Age, Age < 79, NA))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean you want to make it a NaN value, right? If so, you can try

```
titanic_train %>% mutate(Age = replace(Age, Age > 79, NA))
```

Before (Your code):

[image: Before]

After (using the replace)

[image: After]